# Multidimensional array initialization c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a problem initializing the following array

```
char[,] omar = new char[4, 4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
{
     for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) 
     {
          omar[i, j] = (char)(Console.Read());
     }
}
```

when I try entering input like this

```
....
####
####
##..
```

It only take the first 3 lines not all the fourth , so any help please ?

Comment: Remember that everytime you hit enter, that's a character too.

Comment: yeah this was the problem ... Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `Console.Read()` to read an individual character entered, but when you hit enter, `Read()` will return either:

1. A single linefeed character (`\n`, or decimal 10) if you're on a *nix-like platform;
2. A carriage-return character (`\r`, or decimal 13) if you're on Windows.  The `Read()` call directly subsequent to this will then return a linefeed character.

A small modification to get the code you've got to work the way you expect:

```
char[,] omar = new char[4, 4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
{
     for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) 
     {
          omar[i, j] = (char)(Console.Read());
     }
     Console.Read();
     if (Environment.NewLine.Length > 1)
         Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Yes this was so helpful , Thanks so much